# Sequential local symbol definition with logging in Clojure

Tags: variables, logging, clojure

I have a series of symbol definitions that I wish to restructure to `let` statements, but am unsure about how to approach the problem. See example:

```
(do

  (info "Loading primary headers...")
  (load-primary-headers ph-file-path) ; Defines the primary-header-group symbol
  (info "Loaded primary headers.")

  (info "Loading secondary headers...")
  (load-secondary-headers sh-file-path) ; Defines the secondary-header-group symbol
  (info "Loaded secondary headers.")

  (info "Loading data...")
  (load-data file-path primary-header-group secondary-header-group) ; Defines the data symbol
  (info "Loaded data.")

  (info "Mapping data...")
  (map-data file-path primary-header-group secondary-header-group) ; Defines the mapped-data symbol
  (info "Mapped data."))
```

What would be a best practice for designing a program that uses symbols in later symbol definitions and so on, while also maintaining a readable code structure and progress-based logging? The exact order of execution of symbol definitions does not matter, despite the presence of `do`.

Comment: Show us your `let` form.

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of the `load-` functions and the `map-data` function so we can see what you are really doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to trust Clojure's native optimization of performing calculations, especially in multithreaded operations. You mentioned that the order of execution doesn't matter, so you should consider performing these operations concurrently. I would recommend using futures:

```
(let [primary-headers   (future (get-ph ph-file-path))
      secondary-headers (future (get-sh sh-file-path))
      data              (future (get-data file-path ph-group sh-group))
      mapped-data       (future (map-data file-path ph-group sh-group))]
  (do-something-with @primary-headers @secondary-headers etc))
```

The calculations are deferred until you deref them with the `@` symbol, and they are performed concurrently on separate threads.

There is some good info on futures and other concurrency constructs [here](http://cmdrdats.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/a-look-at-clojure-concurrency-primitives-delay-future-and-promise).

EDIT: If you still want to keep your logging statements like `(info "Loading primary headers...")`, you could include them in each `future`. The logging won't occur until you deref each `future`, and the nice thing is that futures cache results, so you can even deref them multiple times and the logging will only occur once, which I'm assuming is the behavior you would want (you don't want to log "Loading primary headers" every time you use `@primary-headers`).

Comment: In your example, shouldn't `ph-group` and `sh-group` be `primary-headers` and `secondary-headers` ? Also, is the `do-something-with` only beneath the `let` binding because it is not creating a symbol?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I took the liberty of renaming some of your symbols for the sake of brevity :) I just renamed `primary-header-group` and `secondary-header-group` to `ph-group` and `sh-group`, and `load-primary-headers` and so on to, e.g, `get-ph`. I'm not sure how exactly your `load-data` and `map-data` functions work, but if they are operating on the primary headers, then yes, `ph-group` should be `@primary-headers` and so on (note the `@`, as you would be deref'ing a future)

Comment: The `(do-something-with ...)` is what you are actually doing with the symbols that you are defining in the `let` binding. For reference: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let

Comment: In your example, if `data` is using `ph-group`, wouldn't I need to deref ph-group inside data? Since `data` is also a future, wouldn't that delay the `deref` ing of `ph-group` until `data` is `deref` ed?

Comment: No, because `ph-group` is not a future in my example. The only futures I've defined are `primary-headers`, `secondary-headers`, `data` and `mapped-data`. Of course, if you want `ph-group` to be `primary-headers` instead, then yes, it would have to be deref'd as `@primary-headers`, and the deref-ing would indeed be delayed until `data` is deref'd.